# WPF - access a property value from the StringFormat binding property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

Is it possible to access a property value from the StringFormat binding property in XAML? I mean, this is my XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="costBlock" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" IsEnabled="False"
    Text="{Binding DataContext.CalculatedCost, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0} €}"></TextBox>
```

I need to replace the "€" symbol in the StringFormat bindingby the symbol of the selected currency, which is a property in a static class: Settings.SelectedCurrencySymbol.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use a MultiBinding with an IMultiValueConverter.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Clemens reccommendation I found this solution:

```
<TextBlock Name="costBlock" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" 
    IsEnabled="False">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                <Binding Path="DataContext.CalculatedCost" />
                <Binding Path="(shared:Settings.SelectedCurrencySymbol)" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```